# Kotlin: Get Values of a Range in another Range

Tags: kotlin

Hello im trying to write a function that compares to ranges and returns the value of the first range in the second.

Example : Range A is (22.0..24.0)  Range B ( 20.0..26.0)

so in that case the return value should be 2.0

if Range B is (23.0..26.0) it should return 1.0

How can i do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could write a function like this:

```
fun ClosedRange<Double>.containedIn(other: ClosedRange<Double>) =
    (min(endInclusive, other.endInclusive) - max(start, other.start))
        .coerceAtLeast(0.0)
```

And then use it like this:

```
val rangeA = 22.0..24.0
val rangeB = 20.0..26.0
val rangeC = 23.0..26.0

println(rangeA.containedIn(rangeB))
println(rangeA.containedIn(rangeC))
```

Result:

```
2.0
1.0
```

---

Note: you should also import the `min`/`max` functions:

```
import kotlin.math.max
import kotlin.math.min
```

Comment: I reckon this is probably the best approach, but the logic trips up when you have negative values (like if you make all those range numbers negative) or if a range is expressed with the highest value first (which is still counted as ``start``). I think the easiest fix is a function like ``val ClosedRange<Double>.lowest: Double get() = min(start, endInclusive)`` (and a similar ``highest`` one) and use those in place of ``start`` and ``endInclusive`` in your function, I think that solves it!

Comment: @cactustictacs I think it works with negative numbers. For example, the ranges -5.0..-1.0 and -4.0..-2.0 will produce 2.0 as expected. But you're right about if the ranges decrease. But then, should 5.0..3.0 be considered part of 1.0..15.0? Starting to get complex!

Comment: Oh sorry you're right, I just flipped them low->high to high->low by negating them! And it depends what the OP wants really, but personally I'd consider ``3.0..5.0`` and ``5.0..3.0`` as the same thing, in terms of the range of numbers they include at least. If you're looking for the size of the overlap, I'd call it 2 and not 0, y'know? There's probably situations where you definitely *wouldn't* do that, but just in case!

Comment: If you compare them with `==` it doesn't agree they are the same. But for overlap, I think I agree. But maybe not for being contained in. Probably out of the scope of the original question anyway 

Comment: @AdamMillerchip your solution worked perfect for me Thx a lot i had troubles over a week with this

Answer (score 3):

What you're doing here is taking the intersection (overlap) of two ranges, and calculating its size.  So, building on what Adam Millerchip and cactustictacs have already done, I think I'd break the problem down into simpler parts: `min`, `max`, and `size` properties for a range, and an `intersect` function that calculates the common subrange of two ranges (if there is one):

```
val ClosedFloatingPointRange<Double>.min
    get() = minOf(start, endInclusive)

val ClosedFloatingPointRange<Double>.max
    get() = maxOf(start, endInclusive)

val ClosedFloatingPointRange<Double>.size
    get() = max - min

infix fun ClosedFloatingPointRange<Double>.intersect(other: ClosedFloatingPointRange<Double>)
    = if (min <= other.max && other.min <= max)
        maxOf(min, other.min).rangeTo(minOf(max, other.max))
    else
        null
```

With those, you can do e.g.:

```
val a = 22.0 .. 24.0
val b = 20.0 .. 26.0

println(a intersect b)
println((a intersect b)?.size)
```

Having the size explicit and separate from the intersection makes each one easier to understand, easier to test, and easier to reuse.  And having `intersect` return null if there's no overlap is safer.

(This should work for negative numbers and for descending ranges; the intersection is always given as ascending.  This assumes `Double` ranges; it could be made to handle other types too, though the type parameters get messy.)

TBH, I'm a little surprised that none of those are in the standard library…

Comment: Yeah I was surprised about the lack of stdlib coverage here. I also thought about your approach but decided on the one-liner to keep it simple. I wonder if the ommisions are deliberate or whether they'd be open to a PR 

Answer (score -1):

Ok well
`Range` some what act as a list so the the could do like

```
val r1 = (22.0)..(25.0)
val r2 = (23.0)..(30.0)
val findRangeOfFirstElement = (r1.start -r2.start)
```

Comment: OP is looking for a result of `2.0` with your r1 & r2 ranges (because the overlap is `23.0..25.0` and `25.0 - 23.0` is `2.0`), but your code seems to have no relation to the problem and returns `-1.0`.